# Regarding bubble display in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, graph

I want to print something like this[image]

each bubble u see is a "li" element

so i have made float=left so that i can see them horizontally. I am not able to understand, how should i display two different colors dynamically.

Eg: If it is 60% and 40%, then I need to show more blue bubbles and less orange ones and vice versa.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) Any code or anything?

Comment: Show some code please... Also do you have fixed amount of bubbles?

Answer (score 3):

Can't offer specifics without some specific code of yours, but: use the modulo operator (`%`) together with `>` or `<`.

For instance:

```
var idx = $('ul li').index();
```

to get the index, and then

```
var color = (idx % 11 < 6) ? "blue" : "orange";
```

to pick the color.

Comment: hi,thanks for the response. Yes, the bubbles are in total 30. I have tried doing something like this   while (i < 30) {

                    for (j = i; j < ansPub; j++) {

                        $container.append(that.template.render(bubble_graph, {"image_icon":'bubble-icon'}))
                        i++;
                    }


                    for (k = j; k < 10 - ansPub; k++) {

                        $container.append(that.template.render(bubble_graph, {"image_icon":'bubble-icon-orange'}))
                        i++;
                    }

Comment: var color = (idx % 11 < 6) ? "blue" : "orange";, this works for me for two colors. but what if i have 3 colors? eg: blue,orange, grey? as 30%, 30%, 40%?

Comment: You can extend it: `color = (idx % 11 < 4) ? "blue" : (idx % 11 < 7) ? "orange" : "grey";`